# Why Yii CDbcriteria filtering results before any actions?

Tags: php, activerecord, strtotime, yii

I changed this code in my model:

```
$criteria->compare('ring',$this->ring,true);
```

to this:

```
$criteria->compare('ring',date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->ring)),true);
```

and now then I load my manage page with empty filters I see only one record and only if 'ring' of this record is 01.01.1970

I understand it happens because `strtotime($this->ring)` return zero. But why its sends when field is empty, and why it didn`t happen before.

It`s works but does not look preaty

```
if ($this->ring!=0){
 $criteria->compare('ring',date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->ring)),true);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` returns `FALSE` if the input is not a date, since null is not a date it will return `FALSE`,

`date()` converts the timestamp into date, due to php's weakly typed design the `FALSE` returned by `strotime()` is converted to `0` and passed as timestamp of `0` to `date()` which is the start of UTC on `01.01.1970` is passed to `compare()`

Now `CDbCriteria::compare` function will not modify existing search condition if value is null
see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail documentation on $value

so in the case

```
$criteria->compare('ring',$this->ring,true);
```

`compare` did not modify the search condition because $this->ring was null whereas

```
$criteria->compare('ring',date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->ring)),true);
```

will modify the search condition as the value passed to `compare` is 01.01.1970

You can alternatively use virtual attributes in your model to avoid the conditions logic in your search

```
public function getFormatedRing(){
  if(isset($this->ring))
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->ring));
  else
    return null
}
```

and use

```
 $criteria->compare('ring',$this->formatedRing,true)
```